# Google Cloud Deployment ,invalid_argument

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to create a cloud SQL instance  by deployment API, when I try to create it directly from YAML file it is created successfully ,meanwhile when I create the instance from jinja/python file  I get an error as below:
**code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/olpr/resources/test
  message: '{"ResourceType":"sqladmin.v1beta4.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Request
    contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad
    Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project_id/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}'**
Is there any way where I can see the invalid_argument so that I can fix it.
Please help me with some valid suggestions.

The resource as   below:

```
*resources = [
        {
            'name': 'test',
            'type': 'sqladmin.v1beta4.instance',
            'properties': {
                'zone': 'europe-west1-b',                
            'rootPassword': '1234567' ,
            'instanceType': 'CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE',
            'databaseVersion': 'SQLSERVER_2017_EXPRESS',
            'backendType': 'SECOND_GEN',
            'settings':{
                    'machineType' : 'db-custom-1-3840',
                    'dataDiskSizeGb': 10,
                    'dataDiskType': 'PD_SSD',
                    'ipConfiguration': {
                                        'ipv4Enabled': False,
                                        'privateNetwork':'projects/project_id/global/networks/project_id-vpc' 
                                    }
                                    }
        }
    }
]*
```

**

```
**Yaml file:
resources:
- name: he
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
  properties:
    region: europe-west1
    zone: europe-west1-b
    backendType: SECOND_GEN
    instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
    databaseVersion: SQLSERVER_2017_EXPRESS
    serviceAccountEmailAddress: user@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    rootPassword: mypass
    settings:
      dataDiskSizeGb: 10
      dataDiskType: PD_SSD
      ipConfiguration:
        ipv4Enabled: false
        privateNetwork: vpc
      kind: sql#settings
      machineType: db-custom-1-3840**
```

**

Comment: Hey Malvina, could you post the code/request where you're creating the instance?

Comment: Can you add yaml file as well?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supplying a region in the Python version. Try adding `'region': 'europe-west1' to the properties.